# Java save xls file as PDF

Tags: java, pdf, xls

I have a simple java program that creates .xls file (open office excel file), and I want to save it as pdf. I saw some answers here but none of them worked for me. Is there a simple and free way to do so?
The file contains only 1 page of .xls

Thanks

Comment: Unless you paste your code (and also, preferably, the expected and obtained outputs), you can't find help.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, please provide more details , share code so that the answer can be more precise, but for code perspective it can  be achieved via Apache POI.something like below ....

```
 //Instantiate a new workbook with excel file path
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("F:\\FileTemp\\Book1.xls");

//Save the document in Pdf format
workbook.save("F:\\FileTemp\\MyPdfFile.pdf", FileFormatType.PDF);
```

Comment: For complete example refer this link. http://thinktibits.blogspot.it/2012/12/POI-iText-Convert-XLS-to-PDF-Java-Program.html

Comment: Indeed I am using Workbook - what jar do I need to use FileFormatType?

Comment: Download aspose-cells-7.0.0.jar, this solution is based on this jar only. link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadasposecells700jar.htm

Comment: When I am trying this I get the error FileFormatType cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 FileFormatType cannot be resolved to a variable

 at xls.create(createExcel.java:97)
 at xls.create(Createxls.java:105)
 at gui$1.actionPerformed(gui.java:65)
 at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
 at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4649)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4475)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:687)

Comment: I hope you have imported all required classes from aspose-cells-7.0.0.jar

Comment: Refer the example link I added in comment

Comment: Cause for  "Unresolved compilation problem" could be bcz of improper jar dependencies, try doing a clean build of the workspace and then run.

Comment: Thanks, it is working - but it comes out as a table... Is there a way to save it as if I am saving it from the excel itself (save as pdf) - I want to keep the design and the sahpe of the page, not just a table...

Comment: Let me check if the format can be saved in pdf while.saving plz check the api.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and vote for if you feel it helped you.

Comment: I will get back on this. By then you can look into below link for any help http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/227782/inserting-chart-image-while-converting-excel-to-pdf-in-java.aspx

Comment: @mhasan Aspose classes are not compatible with Apache POI classes let alone the fact the Aspose is a paid solution. Also the example in the link and the one in your answer are completely different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I have published a library that saves files, and handles everything with one line of code only, you can find it here along with its documentation

[Github repository](https://github.com/rasmi-aw/StorageManager)

and the answer to your question is so easy

```
String path = FileSaver
        .get()
        .save(fileXls,"file.pdf");
```