# Convert an excel file (xls,xlsx) for PDF

Tags: java, excel

I have to convert an excel file (xls,xlsx) for PDF, however I'm looking for a better way, however I'm not sure if the following example are the best for me:

https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/use-excel-api-to-convert-spreadsheets-to-pdfs-in-java

I didn't find good posts and answers here, someone has some better examples ?

[Java save xls file as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572244/java-save-xls-file-as-pdf)

In a simple way I just need to convert excel to pdf in java in the better andsimple way possible, without reading the entire excel.

I found this example, that does exactly what I need, however can't use that because of the license:

https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/sample-java-code-to-convert-excel-to-pdf-using-jofficeconvert/

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886648/convert-excel-to-pdf-java-using-itext

Comment: OK, however they don't want that the excel will be "iterated", like the function when you send that for the printer, and save it as pdf, I did it in the past however I can't create a virtual printer now

Comment: You could use : https://github.com/caryyu/excel2pdf easy and Apache 2 license

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I will test this one !

Answer (score 1):

After so much tests I convinced them that the first solution I used was correct:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.*;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
    import java.util.Iterator;
   import com.itextpdf.text.*;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

    public class excel2pdf {  
            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\excel_to_pdf.xls"));
                    // Read workbook into HSSFWorkbook
                    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                    // Read worksheet into HSSFSheet
                    HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
                    // To iterate over the rows
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator();
                    //We will create output PDF document objects at this point
                    Document iText_xls_2_pdf = new Document();
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(iText_xls_2_pdf, new FileOutputStream("Excel2PDF_Output.pdf"));
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.open();
                    //we have two columns in the Excel sheet, so we create a PDF table with two columns
                    //Note: There are ways to make this dynamic in nature, if you want to.
                    PdfPTable my_table = new PdfPTable(2);
                    //We will use the object below to dynamically add new data to the table
                    PdfPCell table_cell;
                    //Loop through rows.
                    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
                            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                                    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next(); //Fetch CELL
                                            switch(cell.getCellType()) { //Identify CELL type
                                                    //you need to add more code here based on
                                                    //your requirement / transformations
                                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                                    //Push the data from Excel to PDF Cell
                                                     table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                                                     //feel free to move the code below to suit to your needs
                                                     my_table.addCell(table_cell);
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            //next line
                                    }

                    }
                    //Finally add the table to PDF document
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.add(my_table);                       
                    iText_xls_2_pdf.close();                
                    //we created our pdf file..
                    input_document.close(); //close xls
            }
    }
```

Thank's a lot for the help !

Answer (score 1):

To convert xls:

1. convert xls inputstream to html inputstream
2. html inputstream converted to pdf outstream
3. this pdf outstream could be written to desired pdf file or could be returned for further use

   ```
   public byte[] convertMsXlsBytesToPdfBytes() {
   byte[] pdfBytes = null;
   try {
       ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       String fileName = "Doc Naming convention.xls";
       InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

       //convert xls stream to html - w3 document
       org.w3c.dom.Document w3Document = ExcelToHtmlConverter.process(inputStream);

       //convert above w3 document to html input stream
       ByteArrayOutputStream htmlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(w3Document);
       Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(htmlOutputStream);
       TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
       InputStream htmlInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlOutputStream.toByteArray());

       //convert html inputstream to pdf out stream
       ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
       HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlInputStream, pdfOutStream, converterProperties);

       pdfBytes = pdfOutStream.toByteArray();

       //write to physical pdf file
       OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".")) + ".pdf");
       out.write(pdfBytes);
       out.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // log exception details and throw custom exception
   }
   return pdfBytes; //bytes array I'm returning as per my requirement
   ```

   }

Comment: Using this solution, I could get merged cells and all formats intact. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this work for Android?